# How to interact with app under Wine using winedbg?

Tags: debugging, assembly, keyboard-events, interrupt-handling, wine

I've run my app under Wine (`wine my_app.exe`) and I'd like to interact with it programatically or from the script.

So I'm running `winedbg` and attaching to the process:

```
$ winedbg
Wine-dbg>info process
 00000008 3        'terminal.exe'
Wine-dbg>attach 8
0xf7709c0e __kernel_vsyscall+0xe in [vdso].so: int  $0x80
```

but I'm not sure what to do next?

Basically I want to send some keyboard or mouse signals to my app (aiming to select a checkbox and click the *Next* button).

Is it something possible using the wine debugger?

My goal is to automate this process in order to install the app from the script without any user interaction. Or at least know how to do it.

I'm aware there is [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) tool which can fake input from the mouse and keyboard very easily from the command line, however it's a bit buggy, so I'd like to learn how to do it from the debugger.

Comment: I can only speak from my WinDbg (Windows) experience: sending keystrokes or mouse events from the debugger to the application is hard, because the debugger is in user mode but events are queued in the Windows Message Queue on kernel side. Guess it's similar on Linux and/or Wine.

Comment: Is that pronounced "WindBag"? My brain can't seem to read it any other way...

Comment: Yes, [WinDbg is pronounced 'WindBag'](https://reactos.org/wiki/WinDBG)